# Detect in background if an application was launched

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to save the time when an application was launched and save it to the database at the moment it detects the launched event.
I want to save in the database everytime an application is launched.

I tried to do this in android using the service, is this possible in iOS?

I found a list of public notifications in https://gist.github.com/hpique/7554209 and its not there.

I hope someone could help me.
Thank you.

Comment: You're trying save it locally (on device) or on web service?

Comment: you can get the time on applicationwillFinishluanching app delegate method then save it in database.

Comment: @Vijay-Apple-Dev.blogspot.com so far I'm still looking for any API that can notify me if an application was launched, sorry I'm a newbie to iOS.

Comment: listen for this UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification notification. my suggestion is use didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: @LordZsolt on web service, but right now my concern is just to detect the event when an application was launched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Best Option:**

You wanted to save the time only on application launch. So you can make use of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

You can't have this kind of facility in background on iOS. Like android you can't run the service. Everything is sandboxed.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   // App Launched, save the time here
   // Put your Code here

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I appreciate it. I searched about it but can this notification also detect the launching of other applications?

Comment: Every application is sandboxed. That is user's privacy, Apple didn't allow us to do so. You are thinking about iOS as the same way in Android. but can't do so.hope it helps